# take a camera picture and send to php server in android using multipart entity

Tags: php, android, file-upload, image-uploading, android-camera-intent

I have taken the photo from camera and getting the image from sdcard also . Here i have to upload this photo to php server. How can i do ??? please give me a solution.

**EDIT:**

As am getting the string value of image path is : **/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1382769609416.jpg**

I have to insert the url of these image to my php server .

In my database the value is inserted on the field like :

```
images/trucks/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1382769609416.jpg
```

But  image is not upload to my php server.I have checked on "images/trucks/" this path.

This is my server side php code:

```
$upload_dir = 'images/trucks/';
$name = $_FILES['TRUCK_PHOTO']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['TRUCK_PHOTO']['tmp_name'];
 $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $file_path=$upload_dir.$_POST['TRUCK_PHOTO'].".".$ext;
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_path);
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "insert into tw_trucks (TRUCK_PHOTO) values ('$file_path') ");
```

what's wrong in this code ?? please provide me a solution ???

Why that image is not upload from android to that folder ?? Please verify my code and give me a solution ??? But the path is correctly stored on that database.

This is my android side code:

In **DetailsSpecification**.java :

```
static String CapturedImageDetails;
String Path = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);
             CapturedImageDetails = Path;
```

In **AvailableLocation**.java :

```
  class UploadPhotoDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
String _response = "";
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
_response = postData();
return _response;
} 
public String postData() {
    String res=null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.45/ImageAndroid/imageupload.php");
    try {
       nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TRUCK_PHOTO", DetailsSpecification.CapturedImageDetails));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       result_status = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
       res = response.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
   return res;
}
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
 }
```

**EDIT:**

am getting the error when click submit button android form:

****Notice**: Undefined index: TRUCK_PHOTO in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/ImageAndroid/imageupload.php** on line **25**



**Notice**: Undefined index: TRUCK_PHOTO in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/ImageAndroid/imageupload.php** on line **26****

the 25 and 26 th line is :

```
 $name = $_FILES['TRUCK_PHOTO']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['TRUCK_PHOTO']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Seems like you have to use google.

Comment: @Selvin i searched google and done the code like above. But i didn't get the path of captured photo url . Please visit the my post once again and give me a solution yaar

Comment: You need to decode from base64 back to bytes array on php side or use multipart

Comment: yes you need to use decode http://fr2.php.net/fr/base64_decode
but still will work just for small size pic I recomend you to use multipart http request

Comment: Please post the Java code that you are using to push the image to the server.

Comment: @MattClark i have posted with java and server side coe.please verify it.

Comment: What is 'DetailsSpecification.CapturedImageDetails'?

Comment: @MattClark that's the image path getting from sdcard.mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1382769609416.jpg

Comment: See, you set a NameValuePair for the file path, but you never actually send the image itself. You neec to encode the image, and add it as another NameValuePair.

Comment: @MattClark if i have to use blob means i have to encode the image.but here am getting the image path as string value only. Then why i have to encode the image ? Please give me a clarification about this ???

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to convert bitmap image to String:

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String strBitMap = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return strBitMap;
}
```